# How to correctly compute this limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to solve this limit. But I'm having some problems. Can you tell me how to do this?

I have:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\phi^{2x}\ln(\phi)+\ln(\phi)\cos(\pi x)+\pi\sin(\pi x)}{\phi^{2x}-\cos(\pi x)}$$

Thank you for any help!

EDIT:

I split the limit in three parts:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\phi^{2x}\ln(\phi)}{\phi^{2x}-cos(\pi x)}+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(\phi)cos(\pi x)}{\phi^{2x}-cos(\pi x)}+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi\sin(\pi x)}{\phi^{2x}-cos(\pi x)}$$

So I can say that the last two limits converges to 0.

Now I only have to solve the first limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\phi^{2x}\ln(\phi)}{\phi^{2x}-cos(\pi x)}$$

I can see on the graph that this converges to $\ln(\phi)$ , so $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\phi^{2x}}{\phi^{2x}-cos(\pi x)}$ should converge to 1. But how can I demonstrate this?

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: What is $\phi$ in this question?

Comment: **Welcome** to the site ! Could you tell more about *some problems* ?

Comment: It's a constant (golden ratio)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks! Sorry but my first problem is that I can't even start because I'm still learning how to solve limits. I'm trying to solve a particular problem about Fibonacci's sequence but I can't continue if I didn't solve this. I asked this here because I also want to learn, and I want to solve my problem :)

Comment: Are you sure about the formula ? As it stands, the question seems "too easy".

Comment: Sorry this is not the formula. I'm editing

Comment: Here we are. I edited the post. Sorry for this.

Comment: Well, first thing will be to express $f'(x)$ explicitely.  $f'(x) = \frac {\phi^x\ln(\phi) +\phi^{-x}\ln (\phi)\cos(\pi x) + \pi \sin (\pi x)\phi^{-x}}{\sqrt 5}$ give or take arithmetic errors. so $\lim \frac{\phi^x\ln(\phi) +\phi^{-x}\ln (\phi)\cos(\pi x) + \pi \sin (\pi x)\phi^{-x}}{\phi^x - \phi^{-x}\cos{\pi x}}$ is ....

Comment: @Saturn The first of the three parts of your limit is very easy, all you have to do is divide the numerator and denominator through by $\phi^{2x}$. Then $\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{\phi^{2x}}$ tends to $0$ and voila, you're done.

Comment: @Jam Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

$\phi=1,6...> 1$ therefore $|\phi^{-x}\cos{\pi x}|<\phi^{-x}\longrightarrow 0$

The other hand $\phi^x\longrightarrow \infty$. Combining this two results gives the limit

Restarting to your new edit. The main term in the numerator is $\phi^{2x}\log {\phi}$ and the denominator $\phi^{2x}$. The limit is therefore $\log {\phi}$

Comment: So it approaches to Infinity?

Comment: Yes the limit is $\infty$

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post. I wrote the wrong limit.